# SSH into Google Compute Engine VM as a GitHub Actions bot

Tags: linux, google-cloud-platform, ssh, google-compute-engine, github-actions

When I created my VM on Compute Engine, it created a user `user`. I can SSH into my VM from my command line by:

```
ssh user@vm.ip.address
```

My Linux VM has another user called `botuser` that will be used by GitHub Actions to perform a `git pull` in a target directory.

I am trying to create the GitHub actions for this. But I am unable to even connect as this user from my own command line:

```
ssh botuser@vm.ip.address
```

I get the error `Permission denied (publickey)`. I know I will need to set up SSH for this bot to log in to my VM with GitHub Actions and provide a private key somewhere to GitHub Secrets, but I'm not sure on the specific steps. The SSH for my default `user` was set up during the course of deploying my VM from Google Compute Engine on GCP.

How can I grant GitHub Actions the ability to SSH in to a Compute Engine VM as the pre-existing Linux user `botuser`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Try to generate a public and private key.
2. Load the public and private key inside ur CI ,put them as a secrets and establish them inside ~/.ssh/.
3. Add ur public key inside the ~/.ssh/authorized_hosts .

> after that u can access to ur address via ssh.

Comment: OK so I have:
- My private key (`~/.ssh/google_compute_engine`)
- My public key (`~/.ssh/google_compute_engine.pub`).

I have added my public key to the VM at `/home/botuser/.ssh/authorized_hosts`.
Now in GitHub, do I need to add both the public key and the private key as secrets? Or just my private key?

Comment: u need to add ur public and private key inside ur github CI as secret and create a pub/private key using the secrets .
and on ur google vm u need to add ur public key into ~/.ssh/authorized_keys .
echo "public_key" >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys.